# React native typescript number 0 read as NaN

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to map an array and to use its values or keys as data for my return in React Native (Android).
Can anyone explain why the value 0 is being read as NaN?
I have noticed the same issue when using an typescript enum.

I am using:
typescript v.4.7.4, RN 0.69.2 and react 18

Simple code example with console output:

```
const R = [...Array(4).keys()];
R.map((_i, key) => {
  console.log(_i, key);
}); 


Output: 
NaN NaN  // value 0 is interpreted as NaN ???
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

This only seems to happen when the value is assessed directly via console.log or the VSCode inspector in debug mode. Whenever I use à template string the value is correctly displayed.

```
R.forEach(i => {
  console.log(`value is : ${i} is ${typeof i}`);
  console.log(i);
});

Output: 
value is : 0 is number
NaN
value is : 1 is number
1
value is : 2 is number
2
value is : 3 is number
3
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
output for 'npx react-native info'

info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.22000
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
    Memory: 11.90 GB / 31.92 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.6.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.15 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 8.13.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 31, 33
      Build Tools: 30.0.3, 33.0.0
      System Images: android-32 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-33 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-33 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
      Android NDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK:
      AllowAllTrustedApps: Enabled
      AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
      Versions: 10.0.19041.0
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
    Visual Studio: 17.1.32328.378 (Visual Studio Community 2022), 16.11.32106.194 (Visual Studio Community 2019)
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.1 - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\javac.EXE
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0
    react-native: 0.69.2 => 0.69.2
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: That's really bizarre, possibly a bug in the implementation of console.log?

Comment: I don't think so, as the result is the same when in use a debugger and eval the variable during execution (it reads NaN). It only reads correctly when I use it inside a template string.

Comment: Strange, no repro for me! Using typescriptlang.org, RN ES2017

Comment: can you try to console.log typeof variables?  as this seems very strange ...

Comment: Can you post the output of `npx react-native info`?

Comment: @WhiteDeath the type for NaN is printed as number, so as I suspected, this hints towards this being some kind of VSCode displaying issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, this is some kind of **issue with VSCode**.

The NaN output only appears when using the VSCode Debug Console or the active VSCode debugger (hovering over the variable).

The logcat output is correct. Furthermore, console.log(typeof variable) shows the variable type to be number (which is indeed correct).

```
const R = [...Array(4).keys()];
R.map((_i, key) => {
  console.log(_i, key,typeof _i,typeof number);
}); 

Output in VSCode Debuger Console: 
NaN NaN number number
1 1 number number
2 2 number number
3 3 number number

Output via Logcat
0 0 number number
1 1 number number
2 2 number number
3 3 number number
```

Thanks for your help everyone !!

Comment: I'm seeing this suddenly as well after updating from an older RN version. Was there every any fix for it? I'm trying to debug some issue and this isn't making it any easier

Answer (score 0):

For me on [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) using React Native, Target ES2017 and Module ESNext, I get the correct output:

```
Output: 
0, 0
1, 1
2, 2
3, 3
```

However your error might have something to do with this:

```
console.log([...Array(4)]);
```

Which produces:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

So maybe taking the `key()` of the first undefined value gave a `NaN`? Using this:

```
console.log([undefined].keys());
```

Gives:

```
{}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, does it? Why is it printing NaN for the first entry only when every entry is undefined?

Comment: @DavidScholz I was just stating that it worked for me mainly and giving a short possible idea on why it may be

Comment: @DialFrost that should be a comment on the question, since it doesn't actually answer it.

Answer (score 0):

**Snippet**

```
const R = [...Array(4).keys()];
```

**Output**

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

This may cause some problems as everything in there is undefined.

The better approach that I myself used in my code is this:

**Snippet**

```
const R = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => i);
R.map((_i, key) => {
  console.log(_i, key);
});
```

**Output**

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Here `R` is this Array: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` which removes any inconsistency within the code..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, does it? Why is it printing NaN for the first entry only when every entry is undefined?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, I think I may have  found the culprit:
whenever I use console.log in VSCode, the output is grabbed by the debugger and displayed out in the "Debug Console". That is where the NaN appears (It also does when stopping execution and hoverint over the value btw). 
BUT: 
When i read the logcat output of the phone (or emulator for that matter), the values are outputted correctly. So i suppose there is some kind of conversion happening on the VSCode side, which reads 0  incorrectly (maybe as NULL, which is NaN? )

Comment: @jack if you can confirm/reproduce that, go ahead and answer your own question.